# How to get flutter web integration test failure result on terminal

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-integration-test

Please can someone tell me how do we get flutter web integration test failure details on the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not seeing failures - it means that your Flutter web app's error handling is implemented by your dev colleagues in that way.
Try this:

```
Future<void> runApp(WidgetTester tester) async {
  final originalOnError = FlutterError.onError!;
  
  app.main();
  await tester.pumpAndSettle();

  FlutterError.onError = (FlutterErrorDetails details) {
    originalOnError(details); // Calls test framework's error handler
  };
}
```